# ¿Por qué el comando "trans" con una variable solo me traduce la primera palabra que contiene la variable?

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
echo -ne "Introduzca un texto"; read text
trans $text
```

Cuando introduzco un texto : "Hola mundo" y solo me traduce: "Hola <-- así  tal como esta.

Estoy usando termux; cuando llegó a poner de frente  en termux de la siguiente manera : `trans "Hola mundo"` y me traduce  todo.

Comment: ¿Has probado así: `trans "$text"` ?

Comment: Oww Muchísimas gracias ,por aver tenido la amabilidad  de ayudarme , si me funcionó  "$text" ;que dios te bendiga y que tengas muchos éxitos

Comment: He añadido una respuesta con un poco de contexto para entender por qué es necesario encerrar la variable entre comillas.

Comment: Oh muchas gracias. Y también  se puede hacer , cuando se traduzca  y salga en la traducción y diga de esta manera: "el resultado es: Hello World "

Answer (score 2):

Para que el comando `trans` te traduzca la cadena completa, hay que tener en cuenta que cuando se interpola el valor de una variable de esta manera:

```
comando $variable
```

Si el contenido es una cadena que contiene espacios (o algún otro caracter delimitador definido en la variable de entorno `$IFS`), se va pasar palabra por palabra al comando como si cada palabra fuese un parámetro más del comando.

```
comando uno dos tres
```

Este comando tendría 3 parámetros. Sin embargo, lo que realmente necesitas es que el comando solo tenga 1 parámetro, es decir:

```
comando "uno dos tres"
```

Par resolver esto, en tu caso solo tienes que hacer:

```
trans "$text"
```

De esta manera todo el texto se pasaría en el primer parámetro del comando.

Comment: Perdona @Liiam he editado el texto de la respuesta ya que no era el motivo exacto de por qué se necesitan las comillas. Para que diga lo del resultado puedes hacer algo así: `echo El resultado es $(trans "$text")`

Comment: Oww muchísimas  gracias  , me puedes dar tu WhatsApp  por favor o telegram

Comment: @Liiam te agradezco el interés, pero no me siento cómodo dando datos personales. En cualquier caso, si tienes más dudas puedes formular una nueva pregunta, o utilizar el chat de https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol donde te puede ayudar mucha gente si te atascas con algo.

Comment: Te entiendo amigo , y una consulta más: ¿Porque no se me traduce de [Italiano a Español]?  
        echo                                                                                                                                 echo -ne "Ingrese un texto: "; read txt
        echo                                                                                                                                 echo "---El resultado es: " $(trans :it "$txt")
        echo , de Espaañol a italiano me traduce normal

Comment: Por lo que he visto el comando trans recibe un parámetro con el idioma origen e idioma destino separados por dos puntos. Por lo que si escribes trans it:es "Il Messagero" te traducirá del italiano al español y te pondrá "El mensajero"